# Drawing a squircle shape on canvas (Android)

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, shapes

Here is what I'm using to draw a circle shape on to the canvas (and then an icon bitmap on it):

```
private static Bitmap makeIcon(int radius, int color, Bitmap icon) {
    final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2, radius / 2, radius / 2, paint);
    else
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, radius, radius, paint);
    int cx = (radius - icon.getWidth()) >> 1; // same as (...) / 2
    int cy = (radius - icon.getHeight()) >> 1;
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, cx, cy, paint);
    icon.recycle();
    return output;
}
```

But I have no idea on how to draw a squircle shape instead of the circle shape. FYI, here are some examples of icons using the squircle shape:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Path squirclePath = getSquirclePaath(150, 250, 400);
        canvas.drawPath(squirclePath, mPaint);
    }

    private static Path getSquirclePaath(int left, int top, int radius){
        //Formula: (|x|)^3 + (|y|)^3 = radius^3
        final double radiusToPow = radius * radius * radius;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(-radius, 0);
        for (int x = -radius ; x <= radius ; x++)
            path.lineTo(x, ((float) Math.cbrt(radiusToPow - Math.abs(x * x * x))));
        for (int x = radius ; x >= -radius ; x--)
            path.lineTo(x, ((float) -Math.cbrt(radiusToPow - Math.abs(x * x * x))));
        path.close();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(left + radius, top + radius);
        path.transform(matrix);

        return path;
    }
```

Here is a preview:

[image]

Comment: Upvote for the only one life saving answer, thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use a `BitmapShader`.

Note: both mask and image must be equal size, so you have to resize your images.

Note2: this code is developed for Launcher icons and has poor Adaptive Icons adaptation yet.

`baseIconSize` is a «destination» size.

```
fun Drawable.toBitmap(width: Int, height: Int, config: Bitmap.Config): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (this is AdaptiveIconDrawable) {
            background.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
            background.draw(canvas)

            foreground.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
            foreground.draw(canvas)
        } else {
            setBounds(0, 0, width, height)

            draw(canvas)
        }
    } else {
        setBounds(0, 0, width, height)

        draw(canvas)
    }

    return bitmap
}
```

```
        val maskBitmap = requireNotNull(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.mask_squircle))
            .toBitmap(
                width = baseIconSize,
                height = baseIconSize,
                config = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8
            )

        val iconBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            baseIconSize,
            baseIconSize,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        val originalBitmap = if (bitmap.width == baseIconSize && bitmap.height == baseIconSize) {
            bitmap
        } else {
            bitmap.scale(baseIconSize, baseIconSize)
        }

        iconShapePaint.shader = BitmapShader(
            originalBitmap,
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(iconBitmap)
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, iconShapePaint)

        originalBitmap.recycle()

        return iconBitmap
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Mask:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1024dp"
    android:height="1024dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1024"
    android:viewportHeight="1024">
  <path
      android:pathData="M512,1024C736.36,1024 861.08,1024 942.54,942.54C1024,861.08 1024,736.36 1024,512C1024,287.64 1024,162.92 942.54,81.46C861.08,0 736.36,0 512,0C287.64,0 162.92,0 81.46,81.46C0,162.92 0,287.64 0,512C0,736.36 0,861.08 81.46,942.54C162.92,1024 287.64,1024 512,1024Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```