# ImageView with rounded corners, that look like Samsung Icons (Squircle shape)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

I have an ImageView which shows user's profile photo and I want it to have this type of frame:
[image: ImageView with rounded corners]

I searched for "rounded ImageView" and "ImageView with rounded corners" and almost looked through all the Q/A in SO but couldn't find what I was looking for. Those question and answers were about this type of frame and **I don't want it**:

[SO answer about rounded ImageView which I don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners),

[Recipe for making a rounded ImageView written by Google dev](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/).

I don't want any straight edge-lines of the ImageView, I want it to have smooth-curvy Image frame that is used in Samsung Icons (squircle shape). I also looked through bunch of GitHub repos, couldn't find any that matched my description.

So, is there a way to do it in code, or some repos that I can use like `CircularImageView`?

P.S. I am a novice in this sphere, so simple explanations are greatly appreciated.

I also tried to use `CardView` as a mask for `ImageView` but couldn't get the desired look.

Comment: The shape itself is called a squircle. This shows you how you can override a View and draw a squircle on the Canvas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206406/drawing-a-squircle-shape-on-canvas-android.

Comment: Whoa, @TheWanderer you are the man, pff "squircle" eh :) Checking it out...

Comment: create a custom class as per the shape you required which extends the imageview and use that class in your layout file as imageview.. that will do the thing.