# Android: Create a view similar to a system toggle

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, material-design, android-cardview

I'm trying to design a View which resembles the android system toggles, as shown below. (The goal is really just to achieve buttons with that particular shape and an icon inside). Here is an example.

[OxygenOs System toggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwV63.jpg)

They look like `CardView`s (with a high corner radius), an `ImageView` inside it and a `TextView` beneath.

An Android app (Shortcut Maker) resembles them perfectly, and even adapts their shape as the system toggle shale changes (From android settings > Theme and Customization).

[ShortuCut Maker Toggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK1vl.jpg)

I've been trying to reproduce something similar but without any success.

Comment: That shape is sometimes called "squircle". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206406/drawing-a-squircle-shape-on-canvas-android).